# Is faster than linear addition possible using parallel computing?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, computational-complexity

I saw on some YouTube video a comment that claims that it's possible to add two n-bit numbers in $o(n)$ time (i.e., faster than linear), at first I thought this is correct since it was written on the internet and everything that's on the internet must be true, but I couldn't thought of any way to do it so I thought of asking it here.

Is it possible to add two n-bit numbers in less than $O(n)$ operations? Assume you have unlimited number of cores/processors you can use to parallel compute.

If it was for example xor instead of addition it's easy to see how you can achieve an $O(log(n))$ algorithm by spliting the number to n/2 2-bit numbers computing xor on those using n/2 different cores and then continue to do the same for the $n/2$-bit number we get from the results of the xors, but can we do something similar to addition? If not is there a proof it's not possible?

Comment: maybe average complexity? https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/papers/add.pdf

Comment: Computer hardware designers were working on this question some time ago. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%E2%80%93Kung_adder

Comment: Parallelization does not affect the asymptotic complexity. You can accelerate the procedure only by a constant factor this way. And constants are not considered , if we determine the asymptotic computational complexity. In practice, this speed up can of course be significant because the numbers we want to add usually do not have $10^{12}$ digits or so.

Comment: I think you are describing two different things. At the beginning you are adding ''two'' n-bit number. At the end you are talking about to xor all the bits of ''one'' n-bit number. The xor of ''two'' n-bit number takes only one step if you have n processors

Comment: @peter on n (hypothetical) machine were you have an unlimited number of processors I think your argument is wrong.

Comment: @miracle173 With this argument, integer factorization can be done in one step ($O(1)$) even using trial division : Just use a computer for every prime number upto $\sqrt{N}$ to check whether this prime divides $N$.

Comment: I think there is a confusion about *time* and *number of operations*. For parallel computation, what matters is the depth of the circuit (corresponding to "time", since each level of a circuit can be done in parallel). This may be relevant/useful to read: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/02-810notes/lecture13.pdf

Comment: @peter you can do it in O(1) time, but you need  a exponential number of processors processors. But I looked into this subject.

Comment: @miracle You can't do it in O(1), even if for every a,b smaller than $\sqrt{n}$ you have a processor that checks if $ab=n$ the algorithm still need to compute mutipication which will take at best $O(\log\log n)$ time and then it means you calculatet for $O(n)$ pairs of $a,b$ whether or not they are factors of $n$ but then you also need to return one of those pairs, which is basically equivelent for an OR operation and that will take an extra O(logn).

Comment: @TomerWolberg yes, of course. this was a very sloppy formulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult to get $O(\log n)$ time (i.e. gate delays). It is of course wrong to say "$O(\log n)$ *operations*", because obviously you need $Ω(n)$ work (i.e. gates).

The trick is to define **two** carryover bits for each block, one for the actual carryover and one for the carryover *if* there an extra one was added to that block. Specifically, for each pair of positions $a,b$ with $a ≤ b$, let $c_0(a,b)$ be the carryover bit for adding the bits at positions $[a,b)$ in the inputs, and let $c_1(a,b)$ be the carryover bit for adding the same bits *but plus an extra one*. (Here the positions start from $0$ at the least significant bit to $n-1$ at the most significant bit.)

For example, if the bits at positions $[a,b)$ were `1101` and `0010` then adding them yields `1111` (no carryover) but adding an extra one yields `10000` (has carryover), hence $c_0(a,b) = 0$ and $c_1(a,b) = 1$.

The **key observation** is that for any positions $a,b,c$ with $a ≤ b ≤ c$, you can compute $c_0(a,c)$ and $c_1(a,c)$ from $c_0(a,b)$ and $c_1(a,b)$ and $c_0(b,c)$ and $c_1(b,c)$! (I will leave this as an easy exercise for you.)

Using this recursive relation we can easily construct a log-depth recursive circuit that computes $c_0(a,b)$ and $c_1(a,b)$ for every positions $a$ and $b = a+2^k$ where $k∈ℕ$, using a balanced binary tree with an $O(1)$-sized circuit at each node. This recursive computation takes a single upward pass.

Note that $c_0(0,2^k)$ is the true carryover bit for adding the first $2^k$ bits. All we need now is to compute $c_0(0,b)$ for every $b$ and we would be done! Indeed we can easily do so by a single downward pass on the same binary tree. (I will leave this as an exercise for you as well.)

Comment: Note that this can be made to work even in *constant* depth if gates can have an arbitrary number of inputs (the so-called [AC0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC0) class): http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jyc/02-810notes/lecture13.pdf

Comment: @ClementC.: But with unbounded fan-in it becomes quite trivial and uninteresting, doesn't it? =)

Comment: Well... given that AC0$\subseteq$NC1, the statement that addition is doable with constant-depth, unbounded fan-in circuits is actually a *stronger* statement than the $\log$-depth, bounded fan-in one...

Comment: @ClementC.: Well... you could post another answer giving your solution via that inclusion. I think it's sufficiently different from mine (even after expanding the proof of that inclusion) to merit some attention.

Comment: Fair... Though I only originally meant it as a comment to your (very good) answer.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on a comment to [user21820's excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231103/75808): one can actually show that addition can be implemented in *constant depth*, with a polynomial-size circuit involving AND, NOT, and OR gates with arbitrary fan-in. That is, in circuit complexity terms, addition can be implemented in [the class $\textsf{AC}_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC0).

See, for instance, [those lecture notes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ejyc/02-810notes/lecture13.pdf).

Now, the "arbitrary fan-in" part may sound like a big assumption; however, since it is known that $\textsf{AC}_0\subseteq \textsf{NC}_1$ (where [$\textsf{NC}_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)) is the class of functions computable by $O(\log n)$-depth, poly-size circuits with fan-in $\leq 2$ gates), this is in fact a *stronger* statement than saying addition can be implemented in logarithmic depth.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer! =)

Comment: Interestingly, going back to the OP's example of XOR(a.k.a. Parity): XOR is *not* in AC0 (but is in NC1).